# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 + MSTest: debugging unit test hangs

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

There already are posts about this issue, but those situations are somewhat different and none of the solutions work.

When I run unit tests on my Visual Studio 2008 SP1 without debugging, everything is fine. But when I debug them, Visual Studio hangs most of the time. The GUI-context never switches to debug mode and the test hangs as pending.

What's different here, as opposed to most people having this, is:

- VSTesthost hangs at 0% CPU, not 100%.
- Debugging doesn't even start. The reports I found mention that it hangs when executing the last statement, but I can't get it that far.

I already applied [Visual Studio Hotfix KB970449](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=19617), but that didn't solve the issue.

[This post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/403799/unit-tests-never-complete-vstesthost-hangs-at-100-cpu) is from February 2012 and describes the same issue I have (and even with Visual Studio 2010 as well), but no solution.

My PC already has all capitals in its host name. It's ICT003.

Comment: Link broken. "Page Not Found" for feb 2012 link.

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure the link worked before.